# How to replace a specific character in a string (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a caesar's cipher in Python. I'm nearly finished but I'm running into an issue when converting the `ord()` of characters like `' '`

```
message = input('What is your message? ')
shift = input('What number do you want to shift the letters in your message by? ')
def Cipher(message,shift):
    final_cipher = ''
    for ch in message:
        shift_convert = ord(ch) + int(shift)
        print(shift_convert)

Cipher(message,shift)
```

when I run this code with the message `"test run"` and a shift of `2` I get this:

```
118
103
117
118
34
116
119
112
```

How would I change that `34` and only that `34` in `shift_convert`? I'm thinking of subtracting the shift value to turn it back into `' '` but I don't know how to make that happen. Can you give me some tips?

Comment: What would shift one of `z` be?

Comment: oh I didn't even think of that, a shift one of 'z' is '{' thank you for bringing that up

Comment: Okay, got it! -

Comment: The solution for 'z' shift 1 (to 'a') would require a modulus operation on the `ord` plus `shift` value. `chr(97 + (ord_ + shift - 97) % 26)` (where ord_ is the `ord` of the character.

Comment: Of course, you would have to not process this statement for spaces, punctuation, uppercase letters and just pass them with their ord values. (`if 97 <= ord_ <= 122:`, a lowercase letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `if` `else` statement into your `shift_convert` variable:

```
shift_convert = ord(ch) + int(shift) if ch != ' ' else 32
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you don't want to change space/34, right?
You can just check if `ord(char)` is 32.

```py
message = input('What is your message? ')
shift = input('What number do you want to shift the letters in your message by? ')
def Cipher(message,shift):
    final_cipher = ''
    for ch in message:
        shift_convert = ord(ch) + int(shift) if ord(ch) != 32 else ord(ch)
        print(shift_convert)

Cipher(message,shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add an if statement to check if its a space

```
message = input('What is your message? ')

shift = input('What number do you want to shift the letters in your message by? ')

def Cipher(message,shift):
    final_cipher = ''
    for ch in message:
        if(ord(ch) != 32):
            shift_convert = ord(ch) + int(shift)
            print(shift_convert)
        else:
            print(ord(ch))
Cipher(message,shift)
```